# Running incremental sonar analysis in server for changeset in codebase

Tags: sonarqube

I have a legacy application build in java with code base of 60 lk lines of code integrated with sonar server . Since the codebase is integrated with Sonar for the first time there are several thousand issues reported by sonar code quality rules. FOr each run in the server, it takes close to 20 hours in the server. I am looking for an option in sonar analysis, so that the analysis is run in the server only for the changes made in the codebase . This way, I can integrate and report the overall issues for the application from the central server on a daily basis without running several hours for the complete unchanged codebase, whenever the build is kicked off

Answer (score 0):

From what I know at the time this option does not exist. The closest thing this is an incremental analysis on the developer's machine, however, to send the data to the server the analysis is full.

This link talks a little about the analysis modes available:
http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I am already using the incremental analysis for Developer machine. However, I would need to run the analysis  only for the incremental files and refresh the metrics in sonar  server, since the project is huge and running the complete analysis is not a practical option