# Why is my incremental analysis analysing ALL files?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We are using SonarQube for code quality in our CI (jenkins) environment.
Each CI job triggers an incremental analysis through a PostBuild action using `-Dsonar.analysis.mode=incremental`.

However, when looking at the job logs, SQ analysis runs over all files of all maven modules, despite only one file has changed.

How to make the incremental analysis analyses only new/changed files ?

(Note : developers *should* already run client-side analysis but not all do. SQ restulats are part of the hints for peer reviewing).

EDIT : We are using SQ 4.5.6 LTS

Comment: Are you using the "issues report" plugin? Because it is needed for an incremental analysis according to [this page](http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube/).

Comment: To my understanding, the issue report plugin is the one aimed at being run client side, inside eclipse. Here we’d like that our CI job does not take too long by analyzing all files.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195471/running-incremental-sonar-analysis-in-server-for-changeset-in-codebase in that case haha

Comment: Sure. I was wondering why incremental mode is made available to anyone if it’s only usable with a dedicated plugin and a specific use-case. I was hoping for a SQ member (@fabrice-sonarsource-team ?) to provide a more detailed answer.